# Xamarin Android Device Manager Installation Error. The Errod Code Is 2503

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, installation, xamarin-android-player, avd-manager

When i try to install the latest xamarin android device manager(for sdk tool version 26.1.1) i get the error which says "the installer encountered an unexpected error installing package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The errod code is 2503". 
Can anyone help me to solve this problem? here is the screen shot.

Error Message---

[image: Error]

Android SDK Setting ---

[image: a busy cat]

[image: a busy cat]
Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio you had install?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 15 .6.4 which is currently the latest version of visual studio.